# Is there a difference between these two?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a difference?

```
class example
{
    int i = 5;
}

class example2
{
    int i;

    public example2()
    {
        i = 5;
    }
}
```

I prefer the second one, because I don't like giving values after declaring the variable. But is there technically a difference?

Comment: I would suggest reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx    Eric Lippert discusses constructors and initialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer : **No**

Long Answer :

If you look at the generated `IL code`, in case of `example` class initialization is done, before calling the constructor where as in `example2` class class initialization is done within constructor.

`example` class

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit example
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: ldarg.0 
        L_0001: ldc.i4.5 
        L_0002: stfld int32 ConsoleApplication1.example::i
        L_0007: ldarg.0 
        L_0008: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        L_000d: ret 
    }


    .field private int32 i

}
```

and for `example2` Class

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit example2
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: ldarg.0 
        L_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        L_0006: ldarg.0 
        L_0007: ldc.i4.5 
        L_0008: stfld int32 ConsoleApplication1.example2::i
        L_000d: ret 
    }


    .field private int32 i

}
```

Comment: Hmm, so the first one would be more efficient, but to me the second one is more.. organized.

Comment: no i think both are same, in terms of efficiency, the IL code is debug build, so i think a few `nop` instruction are there, if u do not count the `nop` instruction then both have some number of IL instruction

Comment: Oh, then I guess example2 wins because it's more organized to me.

Comment: @user2066764 - yes, its more systematic, though u should take care of the initialization, if you have multiple overload of constructor!

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Yes. If somebody derives from your class `example2` and forgets to call the base class constructor, then initialization is skipped which might be bad.</strike>

I tend to prefer initialization at the point of declaration (as in your first example) if there is no dependency on constructor parameters.

Comment: Huh?  How do you "forget" to call the base class constructor?  It's implicit.

Comment: how can constructor not be called?

Comment: Kirk, you're right. I'm bracing for the downvotes. It's still less of a diffusion of intent, so I'm going to stick with initialization as close to declaration as possible.

Comment: Oh gawd. I didn't even think about that. I guess that's what I get for being forced onto mostly documentation for the last 3 weeks.

Comment: @spender, agree with that policy for the reason you stated.

Comment: for values like int, this is ok,  but for classes, then you are better off using constructor injection anyways.

Comment: @Keith, what does constructor injection have to do with this?  There *are* no parameters to the constructor; injection is irrelevant.

Comment: @KirkWoll in this case, yes, but the asker was eluding to a "general" rule for where to initialize things.  I'm just saying, other than for basic types, you should be considering injecting them anyways, not initializing them.

Comment: @Keith, but that is predicated on the fields being **inputs**.  There is no indication that is the case here, and initializing reference types (that are not dependent on external inputs) is perfectly fine.  IMO, you are barking up a tree that nobody is talking about.

Comment: @Rhexis, you understand that referring to people whom you know are men as "ladies" is misogynist, right?

Comment: @KirkWoll no I didn't... sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I should say, that there can be situations when there is a difference (Though if the code is as simple, as the one posted in the question, there isn't any difference, of course).

Consider the following code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        Foo();
    }

    public virtual void Foo()
    {

    }
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
    protected int i = 5;
    protected int j;

    public Class2()
    {
        j = 5;
    }

    public override void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i:" + i);
        Console.WriteLine("j:" + j);
    }
}
```

and test it

```
new Class2().Foo();
```

The output's gonna be:

```
i:5
j:0
i:5
j:5
```

The clue is that the initializer (when you assign a value right in the field declaration) is run before the base class constructor. So, when `Foo` is called from the `Class1` constructor `j` has its default value, i.e. `0`. But when we call `Foo` on a completely created variable `new Class2().Foo();` (when the `Class2` constructor has completed), `j` already has value `5`.

Though this is a dangerous design - to have `virtual` methods be called in the base class constructor, however, it's not prohibited, and one should be aware of this.

Here is an extract from J.Richter CLR via C#:

> The compiler initializes any fields using the convenient syntax before
>   calling a base class’s constructor to maintain the impression that
>   these fields always have a value as the source code appearance
>   dictates. The potential problem occurs when a base class’s constructor
>   invokes a virtual method that calls back into a method defined by the
>   derived class. If this happens, the fields initialized using the
>   convenient syntax have been initialized before the virtual method is
>   called.

Comment: the point is the base class calls Foo in the contstructor, triggering the subclass to do something reliant on the values of i and j

Comment: I see, so as long as I don't call anything in the constructor, I'm good.